# Template rendering in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi have a lwc component where i am making a boolean var to true and to false on a button. But while loading the component and without clicking any button template if:false is being rendered. But i dont want to render any template on page load untill i click the button.Below is the component.

**sampleFirst.html:**

```
<template>
<p>Welcome!</p>
<template if:true={dupBoolVar}>
    hello in  true
</template>
<template if:false={dupBoolVar}>
    hello in false
</template>
<div>
<lightning-button variant="Brand" label="Make False" class="slds-m-right_medium" onclick={showFalse}> </lightning-button>
<lightning-button variant="Brand" label="Make True" onclick={showTrue}> </lightning-button>
</div>
```

**sampleFirst.js:**

```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class SampleFirstLwc extends LightningElement {
    dupBoolVar;
    showFalse(event){
        this.dupBoolVar = false;
    }
    showTrue(event){
        this.dupBoolVar = true;
    }
}
```

Output I am getting when the lwc component loads is:

[image]

But my expected output is I don't want "hello in false" to be shown when the component loads. I want only Welcome! text to be shown when the component loads. Please can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

> The if:true|false={property} directive binds data to the template and removes and inserts DOM elements based on whether the data is a **truthy or falsy value**. ~ Salesforce

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_conditional

What is **falsy** value?

Eg. it's undefined or null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

What does mean for you?

`showTrue` is `undefined` at the beginning which is a **falsy** value.

What can you do?

```js
get isReady() {
    return this.dupBoolVar !== undefined;
}
```

```html
<template if:true={isReady}>
    <template if:true={dupBoolVar}>
        hello in  true
    </template>
    <template if:false={dupBoolVar}>
        hello in false
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the boolean variable is **undefined** on load and the Boolean value of **undefined** is false, you are getting "hello in false" on load.

To rectify this you can do the following :

1. Have different boolean variables for "hello in true" & "hello in false" sections. Initialize both the booleans as false use template if:true and make the booleans true on button click.

or

2. Have an enclosing template with a separate boolean, initialized to false. Make this boolean true on both button clicks

> ```
> <template if:true={showMessage}>
> your existing templates here
> </template
> ```